# authenticate HTTP request to /admin-ajax.php on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bash

I'm trying to download a file provided by a Wordpress plugin [Pinpoint World](https://pinpoint.world/). This plugin uses admin-ajax.php to retrieve that file in admin UI.

I want to periodically download it for backup. How can I download it using `curl`? It looks like it needs to authenticate the request using cookies (as the browser does while inspecting the requests). Anyway I can simulate that using `curl` in bash?

The following results in 400 Bad Request:

```bash
curl "https://${HOST}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" \
  --data-raw 'action=dopbsp_reservations_get&type=xls&calendar_id=1&start_date=&end_date=&start_hour=00%3A00&end_hour=23%3A59&status_pending=false&status_approved=false&status_rejected=false&status_canceled=false&status_expired=false&payment_methods=&search=&page=1&per_page=25&order=ASC&order_by=check_in' \
  -o /tmp/output.xls
```

Basic authentication (using `--user`) didn't work either.

How can I authenticate to wordpress' admin-ajax, using bash?

Comment: use `jwt.io` and pass the autorization header in your curl request

Comment: @silver do you have an example? Which algo, how to setup the payload, ... is JWT even supported out-of-the-box by Wordpress?

Comment: there are many jwt plugin for wordpress you can use to perform authenticated request, but I posted an answer that uses cookies from an authenticated user which you can get from the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the cookie from your authenticated logged-in user on your curl request

First, login to your wordpress site on your browser.

Then hit F12 and go to **application** tab, then **cookies**

then copy the cookies that looks like `wordpress_logged_in_xxxxxxxxxxxx`

then you can use it on your curl request

example to run basic test,

create a simple ajax request which return a user object if your request is authenticated. otherwise, it will return null

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sample_duh', 'sample_duh');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sample_duh', 'sample_duh');

function sample_duh() {
     wp_send_json([
        'user' => wp_get_current_user() 
    ]);
}
```

run your curl request with the cookies you copied from the browser.

e.g.

```
curl -X POST --cookie "wordpress_logged_in_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=xxxxxxxxxxx" http://mydomain.me/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=sample_duh
```

You should get the user object in your response if you have a valid cookie,

then use the same cookie with your actual curl request

Comment: This only works as long as the session remains on the server. Once I log out, cookie will be invalid. Is there no way to authenticate within my bash script?

Comment: you can try logging in via curl and saving the cookie in text then use the same cookie on ajax request `curl –data "log=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD" http://mydomain.me/wp-login.php -c wpcookie.txt && curl http://mydomain.me/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=sample_duh -b wpcookie.txt`